# Send Push message through FCM google-php-api HTTPv1 API

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to use the Google PHP API Client https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/ to send a FCM push notification through the Google HTTPv1 API.

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; //-- loading the google api client

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service_account/key/project-sfk28as8ff.json');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging');
$httpClient = $client->authorize();


// Your Firebase project ID
$project = "push-test-5f923";
// Creates a notification for subscribers to the debug topic
$message = [
    "message" => [
        "token" => "cO5hrNMFKQI:APA91bFm.......6IYy1phlxIJx2ZNA1",
        "notification" => [
            "body" => "This is an FCM notification message!",
            "title" => "FCM Message",
        ]
    ]
];
// Send the Push Notification - use $response to inspect success or errors
$response = $httpClient->post("https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{$project}/messages:send", ['json' => $message]);

var_dump($response);
```

Here is the actual response:

```
object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)#61 (6) { ["reasonPhrase":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=> string(9) "Forbidden" ["statusCode":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=> int(403) ["headers":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=> array(11) { ["Vary"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "X-Origin" [1]=> string(7) "Referer" [2]=> string(22) "Origin,Accept-Encoding" } ["Content-Type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(31) "application/json; charset=UTF-8" } ["Date"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(29) "Thu, 27 Sep 2018 13:24:52 GMT" } ["Server"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "ESF" } ["Cache-Control"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "private" } ["X-XSS-Protection"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "1; mode=block" } ["X-Frame-Options"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "SAMEORIGIN" } ["X-Content-Type-Options"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "nosniff" } ["Alt-Svc"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(40) "quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"" } ["Accept-Ranges"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "none" } ["Transfer-Encoding"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "chunked" } } ["headerNames":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=> array(11) { ["vary"]=> string(4) "Vary" ["content-type"]=> string(12) "Content-Type" ["date"]=> string(4) "Date" ["server"]=> string(6) "Server" ["cache-control"]=> string(13) "Cache-Control" ["x-xss-protection"]=> string(16) "X-XSS-Protection" ["x-frame-options"]=> string(15) "X-Frame-Options" ["x-content-type-options"]=> string(22) "X-Content-Type-Options" ["alt-svc"]=> string(7) "Alt-Svc" ["accept-ranges"]=> string(13) "Accept-Ranges" ["transfer-encoding"]=> string(17) "Transfer-Encoding" } ["protocol":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=> string(3) "1.1" ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream)#49 (7) { ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> resource(31) of type (stream) ["size":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> NULL ["seekable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> bool(true) ["readable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> bool(true) ["writable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> bool(true) ["uri":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> string(10) "php://temp" ["customMetadata":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> array(0) { } } }
```

The response I keep getting is basically Forbidden 403. ( I can also see it in the google developer console )

The Firebase Cloud Messaging API is enable in the Developer console as is Google Cloud Messaging (although it's not related). Now I figure this happens because I'm not doing the oAuth (not getting the access token) but I'm not sure how to get it as the google-api-php-client's documentation is not very detailed.

Can anyone tell me what functions are available in the **google-api-php-client** to get the *one time access code* that can then be consumed to get the *access token* for firebase so that I can then do the publish through cURL? (how to get a valid Oauth 2.0 token for the service account of the Firebase project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out. It seems the Google Developer Console  [[https://console.developers.google.com]](https://console.developers.google.com) is somewhat limited in what it can do with regards to cloud services. (or at least the documentation regarding this type of services is outdated)

The correct course of action would be to just use the API credentials provided directly in the Firebase Console  [[https://console.firebase.google.com]](https://console.firebase.google.com).

[image]

Alternatively if you're feeling adventurous you can use the Google Cloud Console  [[https://console.cloud.google.com]](https://console.cloud.google.com/) as long as you make sure the service account you create has Editor or Owner permissions as mentioned in the Google documentation here  [[https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server]](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server).

I found the Google Cloud Console to be overly complicated though so I would recommend sticking to the Firebase Console.

Comment: How were you able to obtain the OAuth token? When i use google api library to obtain the token it contains a bunch of '.....' in it