# Migrate from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1

Tags: php, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
public function fcm_command($token,$command){
    $path_to_fcm = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projects/messages:send';
    
    //Taglock Server Key
    $server_key = "";
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key=' .$server_key,
        'Content-Type:application/json'
        );
    $fields = array('to'=>$token,'data'=>array('command'=>$command));
    $payload = json_encode($fields);
    $curl_session = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $path_to_fcm);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    $res = curl_exec($curl_session);
    curl_close($curl_session);
    return array('status'=>REST_Controller::HTTP_OK,'message'=> 'Command sent to device');
}
```

I am using old $server_key and only updated `$path_to_fcm = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projects/messages:send';`, but notification not getting. Do I need to generate new server key or old is required?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication/authorization for the v1 API no longer works with a server key. I recommend that you read the documentation on [authorizing send requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server) to find your current options, and also have a look at:

- [How to use the FCM HTTP v1 API with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782134/how-to-use-the-fcm-http-v1-api-with-php)
- [Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP V1 API: How to Get the Auth 2.0 Access Token with REST Calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49272401/firebase-cloud-messaging-http-v1-api-how-to-get-the-auth-2-0-access-token-with)
- [Generating OAUTH token for firebase cloud messaging PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65633126/generating-oauth-token-for-firebase-cloud-messaging-php)
- [Send Push message through FCM google-php-api HTTPv1 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52538406/send-push-message-through-fcm-google-php-api-httpv1-api)
- More top results from [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=fcm+v1+php)